# Instantiating File from a remote url in a rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to have something like this:

`File.new('http://hostname/myfile.zip')`

inside a controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'open-uri'
file = open(URI.parse('http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo2.gif'))
puts file.size
=> 8558
```